# sqlalchemy многие ко многим на себя

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

У меня есть таблица товаров `Product`. В ней я отображаю сырье из которого сделан данный товар. Сейчас возникла необходимость сделать составные товары. То есть некую связку товаров, которая в свою очередь будет как товарная единица. Чтобы понятнее было опишу на примере. Допустим у нас магазин шаров. Мы делаем товары - шарик обычный, шарик с наполнение, шарик с рисунком. Теперь мы хотим сделать набор в котором будет к примеру 2 обычных шарика, 2 с наполнением и один с рисунком. Этот набор тоже считается как один товар, но включает в себя другие товары, назовем их базовые, у которых просчитан состав сырья. У составного товара сырья нет, оно должно считаться по сырью из базовых товаров. Использую `postgresql`.

Получается отношение многие ко многим в одной таблице. На текущий момент я это реализовал с помощью двух разных моделей `Product` и `ProductSet` с моделью-связкой `ProductSetRelation`. Мне не нравится такое решение, так как чтобы получить все товары (базовые и составные) нужно делать 2 запроса в базу либо использовать outer join, который возвращает все поля для каждой таблицы, но они у меня в большинстве одинаковые. Ниже код как я это реализовал:

```
@as_declarative()
class Base:
    __name__: str

    # Generate __table_name__ automatically
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        table_name = ''
        for letter in cls.__name__:
            table_name += f'_{letter.lower()}' if letter.isupper() else letter
        return table_name[1:]

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=uuid4)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)


class Product(Base):
    shop_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('shop.id'), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_category.id'), nullable=False)
    product_category = relationship("ProductCategory", back_populates="products")
    raw = relationship('ProductRawRelation', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, comment='Название')
    description = Column(String(255), comment='Описание')
    image = Column(String(255), comment='Изображение')
    price = Column(Float, default=0, comment='Цена')
    old_price = Column(Float, comment='Старая цена')
    show_on_store = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True, comment='Отображать на витрине')


class ProductSetRelation(Base):
    product_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product_set_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_set.id'))
    quantity = Column(Float, default=0)


class ProductSet(Base):
    shop_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('shop.id'), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_category.id'), nullable=False)
    product_category = relationship("ProductCategory", back_populates="product_sets")
    products = relationship('ProductSetRelation', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, comment='Название')
    description = Column(String(255), comment='Описание')
    image = Column(String(255), comment='Изображение')
    price = Column(Float, default=0, comment='Цена')
    old_price = Column(Float, comment='Старая цена')
    show_on_store = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True, comment='Отображать на витрине')
```

Можно как то это сделать с использованием только одной модели `Product` и модели-связки для связи многие ко многим?
У меня пока мысль добавить в `Product` ссылку на `ProductSet.id` как `foreign key`:

```
class Product(Base):
    shop_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('shop.id'), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_category.id'), nullable=False)
    product_category = relationship("ProductCategory", back_populates="products")
    raw = relationship('ProductRawRelation', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, comment='Название')
    description = Column(String(255), comment='Описание')
    image = Column(String(255), comment='Изображение')
    price = Column(Float, default=0, comment='Цена')
    old_price = Column(Float, comment='Старая цена')
    show_on_store = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True, comment='Отображать на витрине')
    product_set_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_set.id'))


class ProductSetRelation(Base):
    product_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product_set_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_set.id'))
    quantity = Column(Float, default=0)


class ProductSet(Base):
    products = relationship('ProductSetRelation', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

Answer (score 1):

Немножко не в тему, сейчас заметил у вас

```
price = Column(Float, default=0, comment='Цена')
```

не надо так, чревато эффектами представления чисел с плавающей запятой. Лучше

```
price = Column(Numeric(precision=40, scale=2), default=0, comment='Цена')
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге избавился от одной таблицы, сделал так:

```
class Product(Base):
    shop_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('shop.id'), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product_category.id'), nullable=False)
    product_category = relationship("ProductCategory", back_populates="products")
    raw = relationship('ProductRawRelation', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    base = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True, comment='Базовый товар')
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, comment='Название')
    description = Column(String(255), comment='Описание')
    image = Column(String(255), comment='Изображение')
    price = Column(Float, default=0, comment='Цена')
    old_price = Column(Float, comment='Старая цена')
    show_on_store = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True, comment='Отображать на витрине')
    product_set_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), index=True, unique=True, nullable=True)
    products = relationship('ProductSetRelation',
                            primaryjoin="Product.product_set_id==ProductSetRelation.product_set_id",
                            cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class ProductSetRelation(Base):
    product_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product_set_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.product_set_id'))
    quantity = Column(Float, default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну и вашу схему я вижу скорее как-то так

```
@as_declarative()                                                                         
class ProductRaw:                                                                         
    __name__ = 'product_raw'                                                              
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=uuid4)      
    product_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.id'))                     
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, comment='Название')                        
                                                                                          
                                                                                          
@as_declarative()                                                                         
class Part:                                                                               
    __name__ = 'part'                                                                     
    product_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.id'))                     
    parent_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('product.id'))                      
    quantity = Column(Numeric(precision=40, scale=3), default=0)                          
                                                                                          
                                                                                          
@as_declarative()                                                                         
class Product:                                                                            
    __name__ = 'product'                                                                  
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=uuid4)      
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, comment='Название')                        
    raw = relationship('ProductRawRelation', cascade="all, delete-orphan")                
    price = Column(Numeric(precision=40, scale=2), default=0, comment='Цена')             
    parts = relationship('Part',                                                          
                         primaryjoin="Product.id==Part.parent_id",                        
                         cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

Comment: Вам стоит отредактировать первый ответ, а не писать ещё один.